# cocoa objective-c question about saving plist atomically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, plist

When you save a plist atomically -

```
[thisAgentData writeToFile:plistpath atomically:YES];
```

does that mean if the file exists it will overwrite all the existing data?

Answer (score 6):

Atomically means that your data is saved to a temporary file which is then renamed to the actual path if there was no error during writing. So you will not find an incomplete file at your destination path if the write operation fails (e.g. if the disk is full). Another advantage is that threads that try to read your file while it is written will not face an incomplete file, but get the old one as long as the writing has not finished yet.

But yes, if the operation succeeds, this method will overwrite your destination file.

Comment: Thanks Björn, I actually want the files to be overwritten.

Comment: Kind of related question, I'm saving the files to the documents directory

Comment: Sorry, as I was typing it I answered it myself and forgot to come back here. Thanks again for your help.